# React-Native/Amplify -- Link socials with an existing user

Tags: react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've integrated amplify auth into my application and the user is successfully logging in and out of the application, I've created a screen in my app that would let the user to connect his existing account to their social accounts (which can then be used log-in if they choose to logout).

I tried using amplify's signInWithRedirect but it throws an exception saying 'There is already a signed in user'